# Map a URL to controllers with the same name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, directory-structure

I've the following routing:

```
routes.MapRoute("Home", "{language}-{culture}/{controller}/{action}");
```

and then I have two controllers like this:

```
Controllers
--->en-EN
-------->HomeController
--->pt-PT
-------->HomeController
```

Unfortunately this isn't working and I am getting this error:

"Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{language}-{culture}/{controller}/{action}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:

```
MvcApplication2.Controllers.en_EN.HomeController
MvcApplication2.Controllers.pt_PT.HomeController"
```

I tried to add the namespace "MvcApplication2.Controllers" as a parameter but it still, but I don´t see how it could have worked, but that was the solution I found on the internet.

I've just started with ASP.Net MVC, so please don't sorry if I missed something very basic.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to have alot of different cultures?  You may want to look into using [MVC Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). They're made for this kind of thing.

If you only have 2, you could hardcode your routes like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "HomeEn", // Route name
     "en-EN/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
     new string[] { "MvcApplication2.Controllers.en_EN"}
);

routes.MapRoute(
     "HomePt", // Route name
     "pt-PT/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
     new string[] { "MvcApplication2.Controllers.pt_PT"}
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. It works but why wouldn't a generic form as:`routes.MapRoute(
                "Home",
                "{language}-{culture}/{controller}/{action}",
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
                new[] {"MvcApplication2.Controllers.{language}_{culture}"}
                );` work?

Comment: and yes I will have more than two cultures, but I don´t want to use areas, at least not for the time being.

Comment: Because the route values for language and culture aren't stored in a way you can pass into a string[] via code.. You might be able to do some kind of route constraint but it would be really tough.  If you're creating new areas of the site for different cutures, why are you opposed to areas?  They don't add that much overhead, and would help you keep the different areas seperate..

Comment: Hi Mark, I've don't have anything against areas, I actually don't know about them. I worked with MVC in 2004/2006 with Java, so I am trying to leverage what I already know about MVC into ASP.MVC.

Comment: Ah - not to beat a dead horse - but what you're doing is really what areas are meant for. Creating them early, is alot easier than later and having to move all your code.  It's as simple as just adding the area, and the controllers!  :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common misunderstanding. MVC Routes have no correlation whatsoever with your filesystem. You can bury your controllers as deep as you want in nested folders, it's still just `HomeController` to MVC.

Comment: Yeah you´re right, I read something about that a while ago, but seemed to have missed it. Thanks